# Add object to collection

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a single-page MVC 4 application containing a form (call it `ParentForm`).  There are multiple `ChildForm`s that are attached to the `ParentForm`. Each `ChildForm` pops up in a modal dialog when a button is clicked, like so:
[image]

My ASP.NET ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class ParentFormViewModel
{
    public ParentForm parent { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildFormA> childrenA { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildFormB> childrenB { get; set; }

    public GeneralFormViewModel()
    {
        parent = new ParentForm ();
        childrenA = new List<ChildFormA>();
        childrenB = new List<ChildFormB>();
    }
}
```

I don't know how to make a Knockout.JS ViewModel that will represent this.  My ViewModel currently looks like this:

```
function ParentFormViewModel(dozens of parameters) {

    var self = this;

    self.property = new ko.observable(property);
    // dozens of these...

    self.childrenA = ko.observableArray(ChildFormA);
    self.childrenB = ko.observableArray(ChildFormB);

    self.AddChildFormA = function () {
        self.childrenA.push(???);
    }

    var viewModel = new ParentFormViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

How do I create an instance of a "child form" (say, `ChildFormB`) and add it to a "parent form"'s collection of child forms (say, `ParentForm.childrenA`)?  The [Knockout.JS collection example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html) doesn't help me figure out how to add anything other than a string to `ParentForm`'s collection.  I want the `ChildForm`s to be contained in lists in the `ParentForm` ViewModel.

Comment: Would the parent form need to have *multiple* instances of "A"?

Comment: @Jeroen Yes. Particularly, I have a lot of confusion about what's going on when `ko.applyBindings` is called; what sort of _thing_ to push into `ParentFormViewModel.AddChildFormA.`  For instance, is the strategy to create a new ViewModel for `ChildFormA` every time a valid `ChildForm` is submitted, and to execute `ko.applyBindings` to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use jQuery `$.map` function to map each item to a new object o ChildFormA or ChildFormB. This is demonstrated in the tutorial: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving

There is no need to make childrenA and childrenB observable arrays as it looks like this data is always coming from the server and it looks like you will not be dynamically adding children to this array. If you are dynamically adding children and need the screen to be updated then declare these as observableArrays.

```
self.parent = new ParentForm(model.parent);
self.childrenA = $.map(model.childrenA, function(item) { return new ChildFormA(item) });
self.childrenB = $.map(model.childrenB, function(item) { return new ChildFormB(item) });

var ParentForm = function (parentForm) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(parentForm.name);
    self.age = ko.observable(parentForm.age);
};
```

Here I've also added ChildFormA and ChildFormB which are instantiated for each item in children arrays coming from the server.

```
var ChildFormA = function (childFormA) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(childFormA.name);
    self.age = ko.observable(childFormA.age);
};

var ChildFormB = function (childFormB) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(childFormB.name);
    self.cost = ko.observable(childFormB.cost);
};
```

If you did want to add another child using a function such as your self.AddChildFormA function you would push a new instance of ChildFormA.

```
self.AddChildFormA = function () {
    self.childrenA.push(new ChildFormA({name: 'Lucy', age: 24}));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfdeLs7u/

Comment: I agree with the essence of your answer. It would be better though with some added explanation, a few things in particular. You should say something about why you have `childrenA` and `childrenB` *outside* the parent (this is congruent with the server-side model of OP, but not with his client side model). Second, OP has them as `observableArray`s, and you have them as plain properties. Perhaps you could add an explanation as to why you chose plain properties instead, and/or what the difference is? Finally, OP has indicated some trouble at `AddChildFormA`, maybe add that w/ explanation too?

Comment: @Jeroen I thought I was pretty clear. I tried to give the best answer given the limited information in the question. I'm not sure really why I would need to explain why the Children models should be outside. He didn't provide his full model but it was clear that he understands at least basic OO javascript. I did have a comment about why I didn't use observableArrays.

Comment: @WayneEllery Thank you, this helps clear up enough of my confusion.  There's probably like 60+ form fields between the parent form and its children, which is daunting to work with without completely understanding starting principles of KO.JS/MVVM. How is `ko.applyBindings` used here?  Only once per the one all-encompassing ViewModel?

Comment: Yeah, once per ViewModel